# How to automatically generate a paper-card with values from an input in polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

How to automatically generate a paper-card with values from an input in polymer. This is what i have now with me.

Then delete the paper-card on clicking a button. How could i call all the values to the card and display it as different cards and be able to delete it.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-view6">
    <template>
      <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      </style>
```

Html part

```
        <paper-input label="User Name" value={{username}} id="username" always-float-label maxlength="4" required error-message="Country Code Required"></paper-input>
        <paper-input label="Mobile Number" always-float-label value={{mobile}} minlength="10" maxlength="16" allowed-pattern="[0-9]" id="mobile" required error-message="Phone number Required as per the country code scheme"></paper-input>
        <paper-input label="Password" value={{password}} id="password" type="password" always-float-label minlength="6" required error-message="Password must be alleast 6 characters long">

        <paper-card></paper-card>
```

Javascript Part

```
 <script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-view1',

    properties: {
      username: {
        type: String
      },
      mobile: {
        type: Number
      },
      password: {
        type: String
      },
      </script>
      </template>
      </dom-module>
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you have worked on?

Comment: Ya but it didn't work i removed everything

Comment: Could you paste the code you have right now for us to better assist you?

Comment: If my answer  solved your problem it would be good if you accept it

Answer (score 1):

You can just use data-binding and the properties to get your values into the paper-card. I placed all three values in one card but obviously this could be done separately in three different cards.

A paper card with all three values

```
<paper-card>
  <div class="card-content">
    <span>[[username]]</span>
    <span>[[mobile]]</span>
    <span>[[password]]</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-actions">
    <paper-button on-tap="deleteInput">Delete</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

The delete function:

```
deleteInput: function() {
  this.set('username', '');
  this.set('mobile', '');
  this.set('password', '');
}
```